# What does the nuclear weapon in Fury Roads Survivor do?

Tags: fury-roads-survivor

Fury Roads Survivor (FRS) is as much as a blast as a tiny game can be, and I've been enjoying it a lot.

I've recently earned the Mysterious 'Nuclear' weapon with the description "ʙʀᴏᴋᴇɴ ᴀʀʀᴏᴡ", and I'm hard-pressed figuring out what it does. I thought it would act like [ICBMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_ballistic_missile) in other games, like an ultimate weapon that destroys numerous enemies but which has a really low rate of fire.

However, usually nothing happens until I get busted. I chose Blade's version two as a car, which has little of what can be called 'life', and the game view started shaking, which I assume means the nuclear weapon was at work. However, it didn't kill any of the enemies. The shakes were really violent, which might mean I missed something, but definitely no enemies were killed by the nuclear weapon.

**What does this nuclear weapon do?** I Googled a bit but found nothing relevant except Wikipedia's list of broken arrow nuclear incidents . . .

Answer (score 1):

When you are wasted (only wasted, not busted), you blow up like a nuke, killing all enemies around you. This may give you extra points or oil; I’m not sure.
I definitely like it, just because it gives you the challenge of riding with no gear, then going out with a bang when you die. However, I could see why some would prefer to use the weapons that come into play while you are driving.